# MariaDB server timing out on queries from a node.js server running inside a docker container

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, mariadb

I have strange situation that's got me perplexed and for which I am not sure where to look at. I have a docker container in which there is a nodejs based appserver running and a mariadb server running outside docker (normal daemon), both running on the same machine. The docker is launched in the host network namespace. (`--network=host`) , which means the node app server connects to the mariadb server on localhost:3306. The mariadb server is configured to listen on all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`). Now, when the app server fires a very simple and a short (not at all data intensive) query on the mariadb server - it gets a timeout error. However, this timeout does not occur for the other node.js app servers (running on other machines), when they fire the same query. I also ran the same query on mysql cmd line (connected to localhost mariadb server) and this too worked. Then why is the mariadb server specifically seeming to reject the same query from this particular docker container (running on host network namespace).

My Configuration is:

machine: ubuntu 16.04

docker : Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802

base docker image: alpine linux 3.6

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Can you telnet to localhost 3306 from the container?

Comment: @RickJames,  i have not changed anything with this regard. Should be the default one that came with  installation. It happened again today. This is really annoying. What is the docker container doing here that the db is not liking ?

Comment: @soupybionics managed to solved this?

Comment: @DiegoGallegos, It's been a while. AFAICR, it was a client side (sequelize) issue. WIil have to check.